# Правильное использование yaml.dump

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

```
import yaml

with open("config.yml", "r+") as fl:
    config = yaml.safe_load(fl)
    config['app']['is_disabled'] = True
    config['app']['is_activated'] = False
    yaml.dump(config, fl)
```

Есть такой код, я пытаюсь изменить уже готовые настройки в файле `config.yml` но когда все завершается и я заглядываю в файл, то обнаруживаю что у меня строки конфига просто скопировались и вставились с новыми значениями просто ниже старого конфига, что я делаю не так?

Comment: safe_load прочитывает файл целиком и после этого файловый курсор находится в конце файла, а это значит, что когда вы выполняете запись, то данные соответственно записываются в конце файла ниже старого конфига

Comment: Либо передвигать позицию на начало файла через seek, либо заново открывать файл для записи

Comment: @CrazyElf передвигать не вариант, если новый конфиг окажется короче старого, то в конце файла останутся ошмётки старого конфига. Ну или truncate после записи делать